# Maximize one data point

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, data-mining, optimization

I am completely new to data science and looking to narrow down the search and reduce the learning curve required to solve problems like the one given below

---

I have a data set with 7 columns , 
Column A(all positive decimal) is the data point I want to maximize.
Column B and C are boolean values
remaining columns are a combination of positive and negative decimal numbers.
I want to find some relation and insights from all colums such that I can maximize the sum of column A.

Comment: what do you mean by "maximize the sum of column A"?

Comment: Column A has a positive number in each row , the end goal is to find a quantifiable relation between all columns such that the sum of all values in column A is maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R` you can run a linear regression. Consider this "academic" minimal example:

```
df = data.frame(c(3,5,2,7,5,3), c(1,0,1,0,1,0), c(0,1,1,0,1,0))
colnames(df) = c("A", "B", "C")
df
```

Take this data as an example:

```
  A B C
1 3 1 0
2 5 0 1
3 2 1 1
4 7 0 0
5 5 1 1
6 3 0 0
```

Now we can see how `B` and `C` describe `A` in the best way.

```
reg = lm(A~B+C, data=df)
summary(reg)
```

Output:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)    4.917      1.322   3.719   0.0338 *
factor(B)1    -1.750      1.774  -0.987   0.3966  
factor(C)1     0.250      1.774   0.141   0.8968  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.048 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2525,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2459 
F-statistic: 0.5066 on 2 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.6463
```

This tells us that when `B`, `C` is `0`, `A=4.1917` if `B=1` we would have `A=4.917-1.750` and if C=1 we would have `A=4.917+0.25`.

So, we can also make predictions:

```
predict(reg, newdata=df)
```

Which would be in this case:

```
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
3.166667 5.166667 3.416667 4.916667 3.416667 4.916667
```

This is a simple form of ML (linear regression), where the sum of squared residuals is minimized in order to find the coefficients for the intercept as well as `B` and `C` which best describe `A`.

You would write this model like: $A = \beta_0 + \beta_1  B + \beta_2  C + u$, where $u$ is the statistical error term. You would solve this model by minimizing $\sum u^2$ (the sum of squared residuals).

In matrix algebra you could write $y=\beta X + u$, and you would solve this by $(X'X)^{-1}X'y = \hat{\beta}$.

So we do not "maximise" but minimize the statistical error $u$ in order to find the best "fit" for columns `B`, `C` given column `A`.

Have a look at the great book "[Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf)" to get the main concepts sorted.

Comment: Thank you Peter , this looks like a good place to start.